# Custom separator in jQuery UI datetimepicker add on

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

I use [the datetimepicker add on for the jQuery UI datepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) (which is based on the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)) to implement input fields with a calender widget on my webpage. According to the documentation (see the `Options` tab on the page linked above), there is an optional parameter `separator` which can specify character(s) that stand between the date and the time values, default is a space.

However, when I use a custom separator that does not contain spaces, such as `T` (as in ISO 8601 time strings which look e.g. like `2016-01-15T15:13:20Z`), I can select a time in the widget and it is displayed correctly, but when I click the input field again to select the next one, the browser console gives me:

```
Error parsing the date string: Extra/unparsed characters found in date: T12:00:00
date string = 2016-01-13T12:00:00
date format = yy-mm-dd
```

Have I misunderstood the parameter or is there another way to achieve my custom datetime format?

For the record, I tried this with jQuery 2.2.0, jQuery UI 1.11.4 and jQuery UI datetimepicker add on 1.6.1.

See below for the code and a snippet for trying yourself.

HTML and JS:

```js
// Without custom separator
$("#datetime_input_1").datetimepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                                       timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss"
                                      });

// With custom separator
$("#datetime_input_2").datetimepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                                       timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss",
                                       separator: "T"
                                      });
```

```html
<!-- Imports -->
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- Input forms -->
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetime_input_1" >
<br><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetime_input_2" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use

```
$("#datetime_input_2").datetimepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                                   timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss",
                                   separator: ' T '
                                  });
```

or

```
$("#datetime_input_2").datetimepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                                   timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss",
                                   separator: " T "
                                  });
```

instead yours

```
$("#datetime_input_2").datetimepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                                   timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss",
                                   separator: "T"
                                  });
```

It should give you resuilt you wait. It means for example `2016-01-22 T 12:25:25`. This should be running correctly.

I read pages of that add-on and in section [`Examples`](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#utility_examples) I found this

```
var ex13 = $('#utility_example_1');

ex13.datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt z',
    separator: ' @ ',
    showTimezone: true
});
```

But still I cannot assure you that letter T will be accepted even if it will be surrounded by one space on each side.

**edit**:

I found (in code of add-on) this

```
/*
    * override parseDate() because UI 1.8.14 throws an error about "Extra characters"
    * An option in datapicker to ignore extra format characters would be nicer.
    */
```

and it seems like it does not run correctly.

Comment: Using spaces works as far as I tested it. However, `2016-01-22 T 12:25:25` is not the same as `2016-01-22T12:25:25` for the server application I am passing the strings to so they will be handled incorrectly, unfortunately. Of course, replacing the two `" "` with `""` wouldn't be a big deal, however, I would prefer a native solution without work arounds if possible.

Comment: @Dirk: Why letter `T`? Why not else character? For example comma (`,`) or semicolon (`;`).

Comment: Because the values are used in `GetMap` requests on a GeoServer WMS service. Unfortunately, [this is (to my knowledge) the only accepted format in GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/time.html). It is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which many applications use, so it is not that uncommon to separate date and time with a `T`.

Comment: Recently I found something very interesting in code of that add-on. It is added to text of my answer. Problem is that I don't know how to fix this bug in add-on. But probably it may be avoided - with using of else way of re-setting of date and time in input field - or in additional handling during saving into DB or so.